# How to instantiate JQuery UI widget by string?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Do you know how to instantiate JQuery UI widget by string?

Let's illustrate it with some sample code. Given the html link element below:

```
<a id="testLink" href="#">Test Link</a>
```

Normally, we can make it into button using code below:

```
$('#testLink').button();
```

What if I want to instantiate the button with string, for example:

```
var widget='button';
$('#testLink').[widget]();
```

Of course the code block above is not working (It is just for illustration purpose only), otherwise you will not see this question.

Please advice.

Thanks,

Chee Kin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the dot when you're using the [] accessor. This should work:

```
var widget='button';
$('#testLink')[widget]();
```